# BottomSheet move to top of screen when changing visibility of its component

Tags: android-studio

I have a bottom sheet with a NestedScrollView inside (see below). When I press on a FAB button, I want to make some parts in this NestedScrollView invisible. But when I change some linearlayouts visibilities to GONE, bottomsheet fly aways from the top.

My XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/messageOptionBottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/back_miscellaneous"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">


    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/textSecondary" />

   

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDeleteMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_22sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_22sdp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_remove" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_medium"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="@string/delete_message"
            android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textConfirmDelete"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_medium"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="@string/confirm"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your bottom sheet is moving top because you are using

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

remove this line from your layoutDeleteMessage (Linear layout)
Hope this solve your problem